# Trigger an airflow DAG asynchronous by a database trigger

Tags: postgresql, events, airflow-scheduler

I want to consolidate a couple of historically grown scripts (Python, Bash and Powershell) which purpose is to sync data between a lot of different database backends (mostly postgres, but also oracle and sqlserver) and on different sites. There isn't really a master, its more like a loose couple of partner companies working on the same domain specific use cases, everyone with its own data silo and its my job to hold all this together as good as I can.

Currently those scripts I mentioned are cron scheduled and need to run on the origin server where a dataset gets initially written, to sync it to every partner over night.

I am also familiar with and use Apache Airflow in another project. So my idea was to use an workflow management tool like Airflow to streamline the sync process and get it more centralized. But also with Airflow there is only a time interval scheduler available to trigger a DAG.

As most writes come in over postgres databases, I'd like to make use of the NOTIFY/LISTEN feature and already have a python daemon [based on this](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#asynchronous-notifications) listening to any database change (via triggers) and calling an event handler then.

The last missing piece is how its probably best done to trigger an airflow DAG with this handler and how to keep all this running reliably?

Perhaps there is a better solution?

Comment: Tbh, you know what to do so you probably should start doing it first. But is Airflow necessary for your usecase? From what I read, it seems like you don't want your DAG to run on a schedule. Imo, you might want to write an endpoint to listen for the changes and trigger whatever script when that happens.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated well, I like Airflow because it offers us monitoring (which jobs did run when and how long, etc...) and also abstraction capabilites . I think the best way would be to write a new kind of airflow scheduler which is triggered by events, but I am not sure if this is possible. The airflow docs section about "external triggers" only covers a call of `airflow trigger_dag` command, but I am afraid of this being not very reliable when I run my python daemon script listening to postgres notifications and sys-calling airflow then. I am just curious if there are better solutions

Comment: Have you looked at using Airflow sensors then?

Comment: I've read a lot about sensors yesterday evening... I am not quite sure if they fit, as sensors are designed to poll (and afterwards reschedule) and not to wait until a notification event arises. But yes, I think polling with sensors might be an alternative to NOTIFY->call airflow run_dag cmd

Comment: @absolutelydevastated You should copy your mention of sensors as an answer. Perhaps this is what I was looking for.

Comment: I think it might be better for you to post your own answer. Using Airflow sensors was just a suggestion really.

Comment: Hi! Did you figure out the solution? I have a similar problem to address: I need my DAG running straightaway after the trigger, but what happen is, if I trigger it, let's say, 5 time at once, airflow queues it. The same DAG doesn't spin up asynchronous all the calls.